# Why do many programming languages use parentheses `()` for function definitions and calls?

Tags: syntax, language-design, functions

Why do many programming languages use brackets `()` for function definitions and calls?

For example, in Python:

```python
def f(): ...

f()
```

In Go:

```go
func f() { ... }

f()
```

Many other languages use similar syntax.

Comment: Because that is the [mathematical notation for applying a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation).

Comment: @alephalpha thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Because of math functions.

Like this:

```
f(x) = x + 5
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation)

Comment: That said, many functions, such as `sin`, are often written without parentheses in math.

Answer (score -8):

### Warning: This Idea is not Yet Widely Adopted

Below, I describe why we write functions definitions and function calls with parentheses `()`.

However, I will warn you, that this newer model for programming languages and is ***not*** a popular model at the time of my writing.

---

### Parentheses `()` indicate that a several distinctly different things should be grouped together into one single unified object

Let us take the `pow` function as an example.

`pow` is the name for one of the many canonical function some students write when practicing and learning how to write code.

For example, `pow(10, 4)` will make the computer leave what it was doing, go calculate somthing, and **return** with a value of `1000`.

In the notation `pow(base, exp)` we are applying a function named `pow` to ***one single input***, not *two* separate inputs.

The input to the `pow` function is an instance of an an ***anonymous class*** such that the ***anonymous class*** has fields named `base` and `exp`.

That is, we might write,

```python
float base = 0.901;
int   exp  = 30;  

# Below this comment, we create an ***anonymous class*** having attributes named `base` and `exp`
# 
# we instantiate the anonymous class and then assign
# the instance to a memory address with label `args`
# 
# The instance has a name, but the class has no name. 

args   = (base, exp) 
result = pow(args)

# COMMENT FOR HUMAN EYES ONLY:
#    result = 0.04382720037
```

---

#### Digression

> You asked what paratheses `()` do in the definition and call of a function in a computer programme.
>
> I consider that to be a basic thing students encounter early on in their studies of computer programming.
>
> Therefore, the following digression might help you:

```python
float base = 0.901;
int   exp  = 30;  
args   = (base, exp) 
result = pow(args)
```

> - `args` are arguments or inputs to a function
> - `int` is `integer` or `whole number` 1, 2, 3,891, et cetra...
> - Electronic computers delete all comments before translating code into machine language. Electronic computers cannot read or understand most comments.

---

In our newer model of programming language syntax, all functions accept ***ONE input*** and ***only one input***.

Consider this [code](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/blob/7e1daf126bceeded2698d583d847bd7fae0880d8/treelib/tree.py) written to implement somthing known as a [`btree`](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/blob/7e1daf126bceeded2698d583d847bd7fae0880d8/treelib/tree.py):

```python
 def __print_backend(
        self,
        nid=None,
        level=ROOT,
        idhidden=True,
        filter=None,
        key=None,
        reverse=False,
        line_type="ascii-ex",
        data_property=None,
        sorting=True,
        func=print,
    ):
    pass
```

In an old-fashioned view of things, the function has 11 inputs.

However, one of many newer views of things is to represent the function as having one single input, such that that single object has 11 separate attributes.

Consider the event in which a computer programmer writes the following piece of code:

```python
foobar(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

For our example function named `foobar`, the input arguments 1, 2 and 3 are all bundled, by a compiler, into a single ***anonymous class object***.

At the time of my writing ***anonymous*** class objects are not very popular.

However, functions of no name ([anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) are very popular in some programming languages such as [python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) and the [Matrix Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) (MatLab).

The purpose of parentheses in functions is to bundle together smaller objects into a larger, more complex, instance of an anonymous class.

In turn, one of the advantages to using parentheses `()` to create anonymous classes is so that we can use **in-fix** lexors/tokenizers instead of a **pre-fix** lexors, tokenizers, and/or parsers.

`pow(base, exp)` is not a pre-fix function applied to two inputs.

Rather, `pow` is the left-most argument to the anonymous in-fix operator.

```
anonymous in-fix operator
├─ pow
├─ instance of an anonymous class (base, exp)
│  ├─ base
│  ├─ exp
```

When studying arithmetic, children learn that `(10)(5) = 10*5`.

The product of `10` and `5` need not have a multiplication sign *explicitly* written.

Likewise, `10y` is the same thing as `10 × y`

[image: PICTURE OF A SYNTAX TREE FOR PARSING POW(BASE, EXP)]

Instead of parsing characters, I recommend parsing transitions between characters.

> `pow(base, exp)`
>
> | transition from character to character | description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `po` | transition from `p` to `o` |
> | `ow` | transition from `o` to `w` |
> | `w(` | transition from `w` to `(` |
> | `(b` | transition from `(` to `b` |
> | `ba` | transition from `b` to `a` |

Transitioning from `w` to `(` should create a token for the implicit multiplication operator, or perhaps, we might call it the anonymous infix operator.

---

Comment: *"pow is the left-most argument to the anonymous in-fix operator."* - `pow` represents a function pointer. I wouldn't necessarily conceive the call operator as an "anonymous infix operator". In most languages, the call operator effectively has a compound syntax (that can't be broken down further into elements), with the left bracket separating the first two operands, commas separating further operands, and the right bracket unambiguously terminating the list of operands on the right (including coping with the case of calling a niladic function, where there is only one operand to the operator).

Comment: I don't get what this is supposed to say. It seems to be rather about *semantic* interpretation of function calls, not necessarily of its *syntax*. For many parts it is hard to tell what is intended to be *your own* view as opposed to that of *(developers) of many programming languages*. Please consider to [edit] for clarity.

Comment: "Anonymous class objects are not very popular" this is false: most languages that are object oriented also have anonymous class syntax. "Anonymous functions are very popular in **some** programming languages" also false. Most widely used languages these days (except C) have anonymous function syntax.

Comment: I really like this approach for handling `()`, it's one I plan on going with for a future language I'm making (mainly since it means function calls with anonymous structs are a convenient way to do named arguments). But I don't think it this is the reason most, if any, existing languages have for this syntax.

Comment: @Steve The transition from alpha-numeric characters to non-alphanumeric characters `w(b` inside of the string of text `pow(base, exp)` will eventually resolve to be the call-operator. However, consider `3(1 + 2)` and `(3)(1) + 2` and `10(x + y)` when the string of text located to the left of the parentheses is numbers only, such as `10`, then the anonymous infix operator will resolve to multiplication operator for float, integers, or other numeric data-types.

Comment: @Steve The anonymous infix operator only resolves into the call-operator when the left-most token is associated with a function, method, functor, or other callable object.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Suppose that `F` is a function. Some programming languages, such as Java, C++, and Python, might appear to be a mixture of (1 infix notation `xFy`) and (2 prefix notation `Fxy`). For example, `1 + 2` is written in infix notation, but `mkdir()` is written in prefix notation. I think that it helps to view the whole thing as infix notation. In the mathematical expression, `10(y+z)` the multiplication sign is missing. Likewise, an infix symbol for the function-call operator is absent from the string `mkdir()`. It helps to think of a function being multiplied against its input args.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Note that `10(y + z)` is `10*(y + z)` where the asterisk `*` represents multiplication of `int`s and/or integer privatives, also known as whole numbers 1, 2, .... 912, etc... Likewise in the expression `mkdir()` we might have `mkdir*()`. That is, when no infix operator is written, we can imagine an invisible, hidden infix operator. This hidden infix operator might be nameless, or anonymous, just as anonymous functions are functions which have the potential to have no explicit label or name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Suppose that `CALL` is the name we use for the operator which causes a function to be called or invoked. Then `CALL` takes two arguments: a function and a container of arguments. The parentheses `()` serve to create a single container of many arguments. Perhaps `CALL` cannot accept 3 input arguments, or 4 input arguments. If `CALL` is binary, then the arguments must be glued together to form one single object.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon, in programming, I'd reckon that multiplication isn't important enough to be given its own special syntax based on juxtaposition (i.e. the "anonymous infix operator").

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon All those are reasons why *a developer might* want to use `function(arg1, arg2, ...)` syntax – notably not binding ones, as the semantics you describe aren't how many languages treat things and there are several languages that show it can be done completely differently. I don't see how those are reasons that *many specific, existing languages* have chosen to use that syntax. In fact, the intro of this answer ("this newer model for programming languages and is not a popular model at the time of my writing") suggests these consideration *aren't* why the syntax is commonly used.

Comment: What you call an “anonymous class object” is present in many modern languages and usually called a *tuple*. A few programming languages have functions systematically take a tuple as a single argument, notably Standard ML. (Many ML-like languages also have functions take a single argument, but they favor currying for multiple arguments.) Lisp, one of the oldest programming languages, also has arguments packed into a single data structure; in Lisp, that's a list, because Lisp is built around lists. But most languages don't do that because packing arguments transparently just isn't that useful.